# how to prevent current window tab page reload when another window tab is being opened?

Tags: javascript, tabs, window, reload

I would like to know how I can prevent the current window tab page reload when another window tab is being opened. Actually, I have page in which there is a search field. After filling the search field and clicking on the search button, a new window tab (at the same window) will be opened. This is a part of the javascript code which is belonged to opening the new window tab after that the search button is clicked:

```
function affichegroupe(){

        var x = document.forms["formrecherche"]["recherche"].value;

         function ret(a){
                    var par = a;
                    var result;
                    $.ajax({        
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '{{asset('bundles/ikprojhome/recherche/moslem14.php')}}',
                    //dataType: 'JSON',
                    data:{par:par},
                    async: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        result = data;
                        return;
                    }
                    });
                    return result;
        }
        var idgroupe = ret(x);

            //window.open(Pathmgroupe.replace('__REPLACEME__', idgroupe));
            var ch = Pathmgroupe1.replace('__REPLACEME__', idgroupe);
            var ch1 = ch.replace('__REPLACEME2__', visitorid);
            location.unload();
            window.open(ch1);
            return;
        }
```

Please focus on this line of the code above: `location.unload();`.
The problem is that when the new window tab page is opened the current window tab page is reloaded ! .. So my question is: Is it possible to prevent the current window tab reload in case that a new window tab page is opened?...If yes, how?? and what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you `preventDefault` submit:

```
document.forms["formrecherche"].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```